# Can a list of files / file be pushed / committed into GIT using Python?

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, github

Well I have the below code to list the files which were added / modified.

```
   import os
   import datetime as dt

   config_path = '/home/'
   now = dt.datetime.now()
   ago = now-dt.timedelta(minutes=30)

   for root, dirs,files in os.walk(config_path):
       for fname in files:
           path = os.path.join(root, fname)
           st = os.stat(path)
           mtime = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(st.st_mtime)
           if mtime > ago:
                   print('File : %s Time : %s'%(path, mtime))
```

I want those files to be pushed into GIT using Python. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Use python to execute bash commands?

Comment: @evolutionxbox ~ sure, I can give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

you can use os.system() or os.popen() to call git

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use

```
subprocess.check_output(['git', 'push'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

as it suppresses the output and only complains when an error has occured.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [GitPython](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/GitPython/) library in order to work on git without leave python environment.

Using that library you can interact with a git repository both high-level like and low-level like (i.e. you can use it as a git wrapper or you can interact with your file as BLOBs, maybe your case).